# How can I put the Germany map on a svg in HTML? D3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have following problem... 
I took the Interactive map of Germany from Mike Bostock (http://bl.ocks.org/oscar6echo/4423770) and wanted to define the svg as an HTML Tag. Then select the svg with D3 and put the map in it (Javascript). But it doesn´t work.

Here´s some code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

...

```
</script>

<svg id="map"></svg>
</body>
```

It only works when I select the "body". I tried it with an div, but it doesn´t work as well. Thanks for any help!

Comment: My aim is to create a site with an layout that shows the map in the middle. Maybe, there is another idea how i can do this without setting the map in a defined svg in the HTML.

Comment: As per your code,you are trying to add svg inside svg(#map) container . It should be svg inside div container.

Comment: I tried it now with the code below from LHB. But that doesn´t help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm being silly, there must be something slightly wrong in your code which isn't in the snippet you posted.

I'm fairly new to this too, but you shouldnt need to define a 'map' svg, and then use D3 to append another svg to it. Defining it as a div (or using the body) and appending the svg is sufficient.

I reproduced the code fine in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brxxgb5n/

I've just used

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

for the html, and then JS as:

```
var svg = d3.select('#map')
  .append("svg")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, looking again, are you creating your map element after you try and append to it? i.e. when d3 runs, 'map' doesnt exist, although 'body' does?

Comment: I took your code from fiddle and wrote it in a html file. But nothing appeared. The map div doesn´t append svg as i can see in the inspector. Maybe you´re right that 'map' doesn´t exist at runtime. What can I do that it exit?

Comment: @Milana Just change the order of you SVG element and the script, i.e. the `<svg id="map">` should be declared above/before the `<script>` from where it is referenced.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The change of the order was the problem. I wrote the whole body part at first and then the script part.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, and thanks for selecting the answer :)